# Need to get OS Version of the Client server while PB Application is accessed using Ericom or Parallels for remote applications

Tags: operating-system, desktop-application, powerbuilder, rdp, citrix

I hope you get my concern by looking on to the following explanation. I would be delighted with any help here as we are facing one issue frequently now after upgrading our systems to Windows 11.
I have attached a sample code here which might help to reproduce the issue.

What I need is the OS Version of the client server from where Application is launched remotely through RDP Icon of the Application.

For proper difference you can keep OS Versions different for Remote server where Application is kept and Client Server from where you will launch the Application.

I hope this explains my problem statement and will be awaiting for any quick help over here.

Thanks & Regards,

I tried to use RTLGetVersion system methods in the powerbuilder application but it only provides the OS Version information of the server where Application is installed and not of the one from where it is launched.

Also tried different Methods from Windows from ntdll.dll and kernel32.dll but the result I obtained was the same as mentioned.